# How to upload same repository with discord bot on GitHub and Heroku without exposing the token

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py

I would like to have the same repo for Heroku and GitHub (public repo). I am using python. Now I have my discord token file on .gitignore on GitHub and exposed on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `config vars` in heroku

It should be like this

```py
import os
# code
bot.run(os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'])
```

And in heroku, go to your app there select `Settings`[image]

Then go to config vars section and click on `Reveal Config Vars`[image]

Then in `Key` type `BOT_TOKEN` and in `Value` type your actual Bot token (it won't be public) and click `Add`
[image]

You can also use heroku CLI for this, for that the steps are simple

`$ heroku config:set BOT_TOKEN=TokenHere`

Then run your worker and it should work as you want :)